# How to exclude folders in DU and TAR commands

Tags: android, linux, bash, terminal, busybox

I use command like this:
`tar cf - /folder-with-big-files -P | pv -s $(du -sb /folder-with-big-files | awk '{print $1}') > big-files.tar.gz`
from [THIS](https://superuser.com/questions/168749/is-there-a-way-to-see-any-tar-progress-per-file) site. It works very good but I need to exclude 2 folders in TAR and DU command and I have a problem with this. Perhaps there is a probelm with the order?

I tried this:

```
tar cf --exclude={"/data/media/0/!Temp/!Test/bellota","/data/media/0/!Temp/!Test/Xiaomi"} "$mainLocation" - "$mainLocation" -P | pv -s $(du -sb --exclude={"/data/media/0/!Temp/!Test/bellota","/data/media/0/!Temp/!Test/Xiaomi"} "$mainLocation" "$mainLocation" | awk '{print $1}') > "$tarArchiveLocationWithName"
```

but this command doesn't works.

My primary code from script:

```
#!/bin/bash

mainLocation='/data/media/0/!Temp/!Test'
tarArchiveLocationWithName="/data/media/0/!Temp/!backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S).tar"

tar cf - "$mainLocation" -P | pv -s $(du -sb "$mainLocation" | awk '{print $1}') > "$tarArchiveLocationWithName"
```

Comment: No, it still not working. I tried different options but without success :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU tar and du from GNU coreutils with absolute paths:

```
#!/bin/bash

mainLocation='/data/media/0/!Temp/!Test'
ex1='/data/media/0/!Temp/!Test/bellota'
ex2='/data/media/0/!Temp/!Test/Xiaomi'
tarArchiveLocationWithName='/tmp/big-files.tar'

# get size in bytes without excludes
size=$(du -sb --exclude="$ex1" --exclude="$ex2" "$mainLocation" | awk '$0=$1')

# create tar without excludes
tar -C / --exclude="$ex1" --exclude="$ex2" -c -P "$mainLocation" | pv -s "$size" > "$tarArchiveLocationWithName"
```

Comment: You can probably omit `-C /` since you only work with absolute paths.